# 2D Rendering Based on Y Coordinates

Tags: c++, 2d, rendering, sdl

I'm trying to build an RPG worldbuilder. I have seperate classes for images. Like this.

```
Object1::Object1(int x, int y, CSDL_Setup *sdl_set, int *p_CamX, int *p_CamY)
{
    X_pos = x;
    Y_pos = y;

    MouseX = 0;
    MouseY = 0;

    CamX = p_CamX;
    CamY = p_CamY;

    Object = new CSprite(sdl_set->GetRenderer(),"data/Trees/Tree3.png", X_pos, Y_pos, 100, 200, CamX, CamY);

}
```

I've created a vector of objects of the class Object1 and pushing it back when I create a new image. I draw them here.

```
void DrawObjects()
{
    for(std::vector<Object1*>::iterator i = Object.begin(); i != Object.end(); ++i)
    {
        (*i)->Draw();
    }
}
```

Now the rendering is done by the order the objects are created. I want to do the rendering based on y values of each object. I did a lot of research but couldn't find any example code. I also have other classes for other images. So I tried something on my own to sort y values and detect which y value corresponds to which object. But I'm stuck here.

```
int a;
void DoChanges()
{
    if(ChangeMade)
    {
        a = 0;

        for(std::vector<Object1*>::iterator i = Object1.begin(); i != Object1.end(); ++i)
        {
            ObjectArray[a] = (*i)->GetY();
            a++;
        }
        for(std::vector<Object2*>::iterator i = Object2.begin(); i != Object2.end(); ++i)
        {
            ObjectArray[a] = (*i)->GetY();
            a++;
        }
        ...

        SIZE = Object1.size() + Object2.size() + Object3.size() + ...;

        sort(ObjectArray, ObjectArray + SIZE);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                if(tree1[j]->GetY() == ObjectArray[i])
                {
                }
                else if(tree2[j]->GetY() == ObjectArray[i])
                {
                }
                ...
            }
        }

        ChangeMade = false;
    }
```

Is there a way to create an array of pointers to store the addresses of objects to different classes by their y values and use this array to do the rendering? Or do you have any suggestions on how to handle creating objects and rendering or any useful links?

Comment: You forgot to mention what's the code doing right now.

Comment: It's not working right now because I couldn't take it further than detecting which Y coordinate corresponds to which object.